# Finding a Needle (object) in a Haystack (parent object) Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-4

I have an Entity Framework 4 project that has built up some brute-force searching code that I'd like to reduce to more generic, and more manageable chunks.

One of my Partial Classes, the Run object, contains Navigation Properties (Entity Collections) to other objects (Run.Nodes, Run.Arcs), as well as Scalars (GUID, Version #), and singlular Navigation Properties (Entity Objects - Run.TimeRange).

Run.Nodes is a Base Class collection of NodeBase, with derived classes of NodeTypeA, NodeTypeB, and NodeTypeC.

Using Reflection:

```
    public EntityObject FindDiscriminant<T>(T needle) where T : EntityObject
    {
        Boolean test = false;
        Type sourceType = this.GetType();

        String needleString = needle.GetType().BaseType.Name.ToString();
        String needleStringLookup = typeDict.Where(o => o.Key == needleString).FirstOrDefault().Value;

        //If we don't match anything that means that the object itself is a base class, so we need to try again
        if (needleStringLookup == null)
        {
            needleString = needle.GetType().Name.ToString();
            needleStringLookup = typeDict.Where(o => o.Key == needleString).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }

        var needleProperty = Type.GetType(sourceType.FullName).GetProperty(needleStringLookup);
        var runValue = needleProperty.GetValue(this, null);

        if (runValue.GetType().ToString().Contains("EntityCollection"))
        {
            foreach (var obj in (runValue as EntityCollection<T>).ToList())
            {
                test = (obj as T).Discriminant(needle);
                if (test == true)
                    return obj;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            test = (runValue as EntityObject).Discriminant(needle);
            if (test == true)
                return (T)runValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This method works great for EntityCollections (except NodeBase).  If I try and look for a node of NodeTypeC in Run.Nodes, runValue will be an EntityCollection of 173 NodeBase objects.  But when I try and iterate over it (.ToList()), I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
```

My workaround is to check to see of the EntityCollection is of type NodeBase, and have an if statement to handle it, and substitute EntityCollection).ToList() for EntityCollection).ToList()

Any suggestions?

---

An update to my question, for anyone searching this.  The code has changed dramatically, and I'm now using Delegates as SearchActions, and have a generic FindSomething routine that uses those delegates instead of having several search routines each using their own type of input.

The things to note are:

- The method of detection for determining if my object I pulled with
  reflection is an EntityObject or an EntityCollection
- I use a private method to iterate over the EntityCollection that I
  pass from my generic FindSomething routine.  This takes care of the
  base-class comparisons
- By having the private method to call, I avoid having to use casting on the EntityCollection - this goes away: (runValue as EntityCollection) as well as (obj as T)
- I have created a dynamic Object Dictionary when I instantiate our
  application - I go through our collection of objects and map objects
  and the properties we care about so I don't have to brute force
  through an entire object every search
- I use dynamic instead of var - I love dynamic! And I no longer cast
  before doing a search.
- The function is recursive - the SearchAction delegate gets called
  again during the iteration code in the IterateThroughEntityCollection
  method.

Good? Bad? Comments? Feedback? It works for me, and it's fast.

Here's the revised code:

```
private EntityObject FindSomething<T>(Run haystack, T needle, SearchAction<T> sa)
{
    //First, assume we haven't found anything
    Boolean test = false;

    //Next, go through all the objects in a run and see if we find anything
    //No need to go through Arcs, if the needle is a type of NodeBase, etc.

    Type oldRunElementProperty = TypeReference.RunElementDictionary.Where(o => o.Key == type).Single().Key;
    PropertyInfo runValuePropertyToChange = TypeReference.RunElementDictionary.Where(o => o.Key == type).Single().Value;
    dynamic runValue = runValuePropertyToChange.GetValue(haystack, null);

    //Check to see if we're dealing with an EntityCollection or an EntityObject.  If it is an EntityObject, we can set that value
    //directly.  If it is a collection, we need to use the generic method
    if (runValuePropertyToChange.PropertyType.IsGenericType && runValuePropertyToChange.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
    {
        EntityObject result = IterateThroughEntityCollection(runValue, needle, sa);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    else
    {
        test = sa(runValue, needle); if (test == true) return runValue;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Private EntityCollection iterator.

```
    private EntityObject IterateThroughEntityCollection<T,U>(EntityCollection<T> haystack, U needle, SearchAction<U> sa) where T: EntityObject
    {
        Boolean test = false;
        foreach(dynamic obj in haystack)
        {
            test = sa(obj, needle); 
            if (test == true) return obj;
        }
        return null;
    }
```